# Excel absolute lock formulas from different sheets

Tags: excel, insert, locking

| 11-Dec | 18-dec | 25-dec | ------ | 11-Dec | 18-dec | 25-dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |

What I am expecting to get

| 18-Dec | 25-dec | 1-jan | ------ | 1-jan | 25-dec | 18-dec | 11-dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |

I am trying to insert a new column and just get the 3 most left column dates.

I tried =$E$1 for A1, but when I insert a new column, the formula automatically changes to =$F$1 and results in 25-dec.

My goal is to apply this to reference cells from another sheet.

Comment: `=INDEX(1:1,,6)`

Comment: The data seems to be gone in your transcription.